# Web Service Security: REST-interface for PKI (like XKMS for SOAP)

Tags: json, web-services, rest, ws-security, pki

I know there are a lot of new standards for REST-Security, like

- JWE (JSON Web Encryption)
- JWS (JSON Web Signature) or
- JWK (JSON Web Key)

which do, in essence, what WS-Encryption, WS-Signature, etc. do in the SOAP world.

So I thought: What's the equivalent to XKMS in the REST-Security world?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently, to the best of my knowledge, no equivalent standard (or pseudo-standard, really) for REST.  In theory, it shouldn't be hard to create one on your own, should the need arise.  However, it's important to have a very good understanding of the fundamentals of PKI to ensure that you're handling things like digital signatures and keys properly.